# what does AWS CodePipeline build provider do?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, aws-codepipeline, buildprovider

I am beginner at using AWS .so i want to ask some questions about CodePipeline.

so all i know about CodePipeline ,that i can connect it to github repo to let my app updated automatically ... then when i am doing the steps something called build provider appeared (its optional) .. and when i skip it it says "Your pipeline will not include a build stage"

so why do i have to do a build provider when my project compiled and build successfully locally on my PC ,i know its an optional step ,so can i know what it do exaclty ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are automating your code deployment process you cannot build your code locally as its a manual process.

To Automate the process code-pipeline has a build provider which can build your code as n when required. So, that you don't need to checkout the code locally and build before deploying.

Comment: thanks for fast responding that helped me alot ... so i got 2 build providers AWS codeBuild and Add Jenkins .. what is the deference between them ?

Comment: Jenkins is an alternate to AWS code-pipeline which can automate the process of building the code & deploying it. 

Build provider is the actual code builder Maven in case of Java which can actually compile the code & make a deployable package.

Comment: You can either use Jenkins or code-pipeline to automate the stuff. In case of Jenkins you need to configure maven yourself. But, with code-pipeline the build provider already has the maven preconfigured which can build your code.